# uncompyle pyc file => names in output only have underscores, "0"s, "O"s, "o"s, "l"s and "1"s

Tags: python

im trying to reverse engineer pyc file. so i'm running uncompyle and i'm getting very strange output.

```
import os, sys, shutil, re, base64, inspect, socket, datetime, itertools, random, colorsys
from functools import partial
import collections, uuid
from string import ascii_uppercase
o___O_0___0___O_O____0_0__O_____o_o____1 = uuid.getnode
o___o__1___o_O_o_____O____O____0_l___O_0 = os.path.getmtime
o__l_____o_o____o____O_o____1___0 = os.path.getctime

class o____l____1_l__O__1____l__o__1(object):
    _o___O___o___1___1___1_0_O_____o____O_O__O_____1_____l___o = {}

    def __getattr__(o___l___1____1___l_____O_l_____1_0_____o__0___O_____0_o____O_O, propertyName):
        o___l___1____1___l_____O_l_____1_0_____o__0___O_____0_o____O_O.__dict__[propertyName] = None
        return

    def o_O__l_0_____0__0_____0_____O____1___O(o___l___1____1___l_____O_l_____1_0_____o__0___O_____0_o____O_O, propertyName):
        try:
```

is there any way to uncompyle file properly ?

Comment: Typically this means whoever built the file used obfuscation tools. If those tools are well-built, the original names aren't there at all anymore, and you need to infer them from context. (Whoever _ran_ the tool will typically have a map from the generated name back to the original name, but that doesn't do you any good).

Comment: ...so, get to search-and-replace'ing (and using your brain to make context-based inferences).

Comment: i would love to, but there is 3 megs worth of py files.

Comment: Figuring out where the important parts are similarly falls under the "using-your-head" side of things. If you can trigger stack traces at points in time when you know what the code is doing, f/e, that'll let you figure out context for the functions involved in what the application is doing at that time.

Comment: @PouyaEsmaeili, "uncompyle" is the name of a specific piece of software. It should not be replaced with the generic term "decompile".

Answer (score 1):

> Typically this means whoever built the file used obfuscation tools. If those tools are well-built, the original names aren't there at all anymore, and you need to infer them from context. (Whoever ran the tool will typically have a map from the generated name back to the original name, but that doesn't do you any good).

– answered by Charles Duffy